# Android: How to read and write a file on a location accessible and visible via file explorer?

Tags: android

I have an App that is currently in the google play store. The app maintains a file and has no internet connection. The file contains key information that must be able to be backed up. And if the users switches phones, they must be able to copy the file to the same location in the new phone. As such the file needs to be in a location accessible to the user.

Before Android 11 this was very simple. Now, for Android 11 it seems to be almost impossible.

If I don't use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the file in mainatained in Android/Data/package.name/

However when doing this, I cannot see the file being created using my file explorer.

So I tried using this permission and Google has rejected my upload of the app to the play store.

So I ask, is there anyway that I can maintain a single file on a location of the phone that is accessible via file explorer and without needing the  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? The file needs to be complety random in it's content.

I have appealed my decistion to google but I'm 100% percent sure that it's going to be rejected. So if there is no easy solution I will just take down the app. And distribute it via email. Several of my friends and I used it daily and I want to keep on using it.

I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: The best solution is to use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`) and let the user choose where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) the user wants you to put the user's content. Beyond that, you are welcome to write your content to `Downloads/` or `Documents/`, with some limitations (notably: other apps on the device can't see it, except via the Storage Access Framework).

Comment: The second solution is not really viable as the file is not seen by the File Explorer. I can try the first solution and see how it would work.

Comment: "The second solution is not really viable as the file is not seen by the File Explorer" -- it is unclear what you mean by "the File Explorer". The contents of `Documents/` and `Downloads/` are available to on-device file managers with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions and are available to desktop operating systems via USB Mass Storage mode.

Comment: I will test this again. But from what I've seen without manage exteral storage permission I have been unable to create a file  in the documents directory. And I got an java.io error that the file exists even though Files (by Google) did not show it.

Comment: On Android 13+ devices your app does not need any permission to create files in public Documents directory. Below 13 READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna check on this, because I was SURE that it did not work withouth that permission. I'll post another question if there is still an issue

Comment: @blackapps I made a question with my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77500638/why-cant-i-write-to-the-documents-directory-in-android-11  Which is the reason I started THIS question in the first place.